# Cannot find JAVA_HOME!

Tags: windows-7, java

Ive been following all the steps to set up java and its compilers and sutch, but i get to the step to change the route for JAVA_HOME where i go into enviroment variables and there is no JAVA_HOME, i have installed everything needed, I have windows 7 if that changes anything, whats going on, thanks x

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7

Comment: @org.life.java I wouldn't agree more with you on this duplicate if the question wasn't "how to update the JAVA_HOME (as probably asked in the tutorial the OP is following) if it doesn't already exist".

Answer (score 4):

You have to define your `%JAVA_HOME%` yourself, **create the variable if it doesn't exist**.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the JAVA_HOME variable in your Environment variables.

Be sure to set it to the root of your JDK folder.

e.g. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\

For some reasons my comments are not showing up.
The command window does not pick up changes to the environment variables dynamically, be sure to open a new command window after you have made the change.

Comment: cmd still doesnt understand javac why?

Comment: @luke - add %JAVA_HOME%\bin to your path

Comment: +1 for mentioning need of restarting the command window.

Answer (score 1):

For windows:

```
REM Set to whatever JDK is installed to:
set JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_16\"

set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%/bin;%PATH%

REM this will give you trouble soon enough ;)
set CLASSPATH=.;%CLASSPATH%
```

Another option is to get an IDE like Eclipse or NetBeans.  They will do most of it for you.

Comment: Where can I add this to Windows 7, so that it is set on boot.  (I'm new to Windows, having used Unix for a couple of decades).

Answer (score 0):

Define that in the environment variables.